# hajj muslim practices

Tags: halal-haram, quran, sin, muslim-practices, hajj

Yesterday I was talking about where I’d want to travel, and by accident I said I wouldn’t go to Saudi Arabia and forgot that’s where Hajj is. would this be seen as just a mistake and am I still a Muslim? thank you

Comment: Why would that make a change in your faith?

Comment: It didn't but I just feel bad like i accidentally disrespected my religion, so i was wondering if im still a muslim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course you are still a muslim , you did not disrespect islam if you want to go to for example your school but you stay at home this does not effect you.